# Create two user in TortoiseHg Workbench

Tags: tortoisehg, workbench

I work with TortoiseHg Workbench and I have two different repository with different login and password. So I am interesting in the way how to I can store and bind proper login/password with target repository ?

Comment: Do you mean that your local repositories are cloned from "secure" repositories, each with a different username/password combination? Or are they cloned from the same repo, but with different username/password?

Comment: different repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really said

> I have two local repositories, cloned from different (http-based) sources, which require different authentication credentials for pull-push

you have to read `hg help hgrc` ([auth] setion part) or [do it online](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) and add to global (or each repo-specific) hgrc `[auth]` section (missing by default) with needed key=value pair

```
Example:

foo.prefix = hg.intevation.org/mercurial
foo.username = foo
foo.password = bar
foo.schemes = http https
```

will **silently** authorizes you as user foo with password bar on http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial* or https://hg.intevation.org/mercurial*. You can have intersected prefixes for different auth on different subtrees of single resource - **longest matching** prefix always win